# Only get single translation from Google Translate API

Tags: php, google-translate, google-translation-api

So I'm using the Google Translate API in PHP as explained in the documentation...

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=src/i18n-php/credential.json');
use Google\Cloud\Translate\TranslateClient;
$g_tr = new TranslateClient([ 'projectId' => 'my-project' ]);
$source_language = "en";
$target_language = "de";
$text_to_translate = "Last name";
$result = $g_tr->translate($text_to_translate, [
                              'source' => $source_language,
                              'target' => $target_language,
                          ]);
echo $result['text'];
```

This works just as expected until there are several translation possibilities, like in the above code example, where the German translation can either be "Familienname" or "Nachname" - The Google Translate API outputs both into the `$result['text']` seperated by comma: `Familienname, Nachname`.

I've been searching my fingers sore looking for a way to only get a single (preferably the most popular) translation. What do I have to do so that I only get one single translation possibility back from Google?

Comment: I imagine your best option is to `explode` the results delimited by comma and just use the first one.

Comment: well obviously this is actually part of an automated process where the source text could be anything. I also can't check for the query word count, because the problematic "Last Name" case in the code example above is already two words and it's absolutely plausible for other two word combinations to return a translated sentence that includes a comma in a number of languages.

Comment: I imagine there wont be many translations for longer phrases that return multiple results. It makes sense that occasionally there will be some one or two word inputs that have different possible translations, but probably not for full sentences. However, I see your point. Unfortunately I think you have reached a limitation of google translate's system here. As far as I know, the translations are created through a cooperative volunteer community, so I think google just regurgitates whatever has been determined as the translation by said community.

Comment: It's advertised as Neural Network for Machine Translation, so it should definitely have the concept of possible translations versus a single translation. There just has be a way to eliminate getting multiple possibilities returned. https://research.googleblog.com/2016/09/a-neural-network-for-machine.html

Comment: The Java Client Google Translate API is having server errors at initialization, are you experiencing these same errors?

Comment: no, it works fine for me, you probably didn't initialize it correctly - also when just using translate.google.com, the same problem emerges: https://translate.google.de/#en/de/Last%20Name